# Need a simple guide on how to integrate the adobecreativesdk on an Ionic multi platform app

Tags: adobecreativesdk

I am working on a multi platform application on Ionic, and would like to integrate the adobecreativesdk. I have not found that much information in how to achieved this and was hoping for some guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the [Creative SDK plugins for PhoneGap](https://creativesdk.github.io/#plugins), which should be compatible with Ionic.

The instructions themselves are for PhoneGap, but there may be enough info in the READMEs to help you get going.